# Getting the bits of a string in C++

Tags: c++

I need to get bits of a character. I haven't used C++ bitwise operators before, and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
int main()
{
    bool bits[8];
    char c = static_cast<char>(0b11101101);
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        bits[i] = (c >> i) & 1;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        std::cout << bits[i];
    }
}
//output: 10110111
```

Comment: Is the problem that the output is backwards?

Comment: Use a [std::bitset](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/bitset) ?

Comment: just reverse the bits in `bits` and voila

Comment: Partly that, partly that I'm an idiot and worked on this for half an hour without noticing. I'll just reverse the for loop.

Comment: If it is only about printing out an integer value in binary format, then there would be easier ways than storing bits in an array before printing them then in reverse order...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change your first loop to:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    bits[7-i] = (c >> i ) & 1;
}
```